# composer brings empty framework folder for laravel

Tags: laravel, composer-php

After today's composer update, I got an error that composer couldn't find `vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php`

after investigating I found Laravel's framework folder is empty. It's empty even when I am trying to require Laravel outside the project.

Any Ideas or information could be helpful.

For hotfix, I have copied from another project of that folder and pasted to the Laravel's vendor folder.

Comment: which folder do you mean by "laravel's folder"?

Comment: @matiit vendor->laravel->framework

Comment: can you show your composer.json file? and step by step what are you doing? thanks.

Comment: thanks @matiit a lot. somehow my cached laravel version got corrupted and its continue to load from cache , after clearing cache the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should clear your local composer cache

```
composer clearcache
```

Answer (score 1):

I get confirmed another simple rule in programming: in every strange situation just clear the cache.

```
composer clearcache
```